# Create a powershell / bat file script to automatically sort files into folders

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I wish to sort a wide range of files based on the name after the final "_" into folders with the same name using powershell or bat file.
As an example I have the following files;

```
XYZ_Featurepoint_A_ABCD.dwg
XYZ_Featurepoint_A_ABCD.dwg.xml
XYZ_A_ABCD.dwg
XYZ_A_ABCD.dwg.xml

XYZ_Featurepoint_A_ABCDE.dwg
XYZ_Featurepoint_A_ABCDE.dwg.xml
XYZ_A_ABCDE.dwg
XYZ_A_ABCDE.dwg.xml
```

I wish to put the files with the same filename after the last `_` which in this case is ABCD and ABCDE into folders named the same as the file name after the final `_` which in this case is ABCD and ABCDE

Please advise

I have not found a solution yet

Comment: Had you found a solution, you would probably not be asking the question. Please edit-in any code you have used in an attempt to solve your problem. Please also provide realistic sample filenames that contain any characters other than `a..z 0..9 _ .`

Comment: Your directory names do not match your description, `ABCD`, `ABCD.dwg`, `ABCDE`, and `ABCDE.dwg` would be the resulting names, not just `ABCD`, and `ABCDE`. So can you fully explain every possible terminating basename character, after the last underscore instance, instead of us simply assuming only periods.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question well, you want to extract a substring *between* (but not including) last underscore and the first dot? Then the following code snippet could help (added some *unusual names* to show how the algorithm works in such case):

```
$Strings = @'
.ExtOnly
NoLowline.Ext
NoLowlineNoExt
XYZ_Featurepoint_A_ABCD.dwg
XYZ_Featurepoint_A_ABCD.dwg.xml
XYZ_A_ABCD.dwg
XYZ_A_ABCD.dwg.xml
XYZ_Featurepoint_A_ABCDE.dwg
XYZ_Featurepoint_A_ABCDE.dwg.xml
XYZ_A_ABCDE.dwg
XYZ_A_ABCDE.dwg.xml
'@ -split [System.Environment]::NewLine

ForEach ($String in $Strings) {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        substring = (($String -split '_')[-1] -split '\.')[0]
        string    = $String
    }
}
```

**Output**: `.\SO\76164896.ps1`

```
substring      string
---------      ------
               .ExtOnly
NoLowline      NoLowline.Ext
NoLowlineNoExt NoLowlineNoExt
ABCD           XYZ_Featurepoint_A_ABCD.dwg
ABCD           XYZ_Featurepoint_A_ABCD.dwg.xml
ABCD           XYZ_A_ABCD.dwg
ABCD           XYZ_A_ABCD.dwg.xml
ABCDE          XYZ_Featurepoint_A_ABCDE.dwg
ABCDE          XYZ_Featurepoint_A_ABCDE.dwg.xml
ABCDE          XYZ_A_ABCDE.dwg
ABCDE          XYZ_A_ABCDE.dwg.xml
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting a solution to this. I am a complete novice when it comes to this so Im wondering is this a bat or powershell script? How do I specify which folder to search and do I have to specify all the names of the files in the script? Is it possible to just say "use the letters/numbers that comes after the last _"?